# TypeError: string indices must be integers when trying to access value from dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary like so:

```
data = {
   "4.3.0 Test Plan":{
      "Engine":{
         "passed_count":0,
         "blocked_count":0,
         "untested_count":4088,
         "failed_count":0,
         "reviewed_count":0,
         "test_harness_issue_count":0,
         "bug_failure_count":0,
         "defect_list":[

         ]
      },
      "Management Web Console":{
         "passed_count":0,
         "blocked_count":0,
         "untested_count":12067,
         "failed_count":0,
         "reviewed_count":0,
         "test_harness_issue_count":0,
         "bug_failure_count":0,
         "defect_list":[

         ]
      }
   }
}
```

And i am trying to access the `untested_count` value of both categories by doing this:

```
for value in data["4.3.0 Test Plan"]:
    print(value)
    print(value['untested_count'])
```

But i am receiving this error `TypeError: string indices must be integers` on this line `print(value['untested_count'])`

And also receiving this error from my python IDE `Expected type 'Union[int, slice]', got 'str' instead` on the same line

I am confused as to why this is and any help and explanation of this error in regards to this example would be greatly appreciated

NOTE: `print(value)` in the above for loop works and will return with:

```
Engine
Management Web Console
```

EXPECTED OUTCOME:

```
Engine
4088
Management Web Console
12067
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're iterating over `keys` of your dictionary, instead you could iterate over both `keys` and `values` using `items()`.

```
for key, value in data["4.3.0 Test Plan"].items():
   print(key)
   print(value['untested_count'])
```

**Output:**

```
Engine
4088
Management Web Console
12067
```